# Нормаль из координат треугольника Объяснения и Реализующая Функция

Tags: c++, opengl, glm

Решил сделать карту высот, Все просто и понятно, одна картинка чёрно-белая формирует рельеф, вторая цветная формирует цвет.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но вот вечная проблема нормалей, помню несколько лет для моделей искал тему, нашёл кусок кода вставил, заработало но верно ли и каким образом до конца не был уверен. Для карты высот такой же вопрос, возможно так тоже можно было бы решить, но немного хочу разобраться и получить 100 процентной рабочий способ. Не привязывая к конкретно моей программе хочу получить общее понятное и кратное объяснения без заумных математических фраз, как почитать нормали по трем координатам, не забываем правило построения точек по часовой стрелке, это соблюдено. Дополнительно хотелось бы в ответе получить функцию в которой на входе ми отправляем три точки, а на выходе получаем нормаль.
Заранее спасибо, очень поможете. C++.

Уточнение: нормаль по сути общая для всех трех точек, так как центр нормали всегда в центре координат 0,0,0, а точки находиться в одной плоскости. Точки задаться трема координатами x,y,z

Для тех кто просто посмотреть, нормали нужны для расчета освещения.

Нормаль выглядит как на картинке, но у меня для каждого треугольника (или для каждой точки) своя нормаль.

//=====================================
После комментариев KoVadim и  Stranger in the Q
Вот что  получилось, присутствует некий кубизм хотя у каждой верни с одинаковыми координатами только одна нормаль, но думаю разберусь. Блгодарен

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

К сожалению вопрос не решён, нормали совершенно не корректно рассчитаны. Что странно, на плоскости вроде все ок, но не на холмах. Там просто в бок.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не уверен что поможет но вот код

```
namespace USMod
{
    
    class HeighMap
    {
    public:
        //Моделька
        MeshCreater Mesh;

//Модель линий для нормалей
        MeshCreater NormalMesh;


        //только при загрузке
        glm::vec3 Scalse;
        glm::vec3 Translate;
        //Массив с точками итд
        MeshCreater::VertexOne **masiv;


        //Ширина глубина
        float height, width;

        HeighMap()
        {
            height = 0;
            width = 0;
        }

        MeshCreater::v3 glmToV3(glm::vec3 v)
        {
            MeshCreater::v3 a;
            a.x = v.x;
            a.y = v.y;
            a.z = v.z;
            return a;
        }
        
        MeshCreater::v2 glmToV2(glm::vec2 v)
        {
            MeshCreater::v2 a;
            a.x = v.x;
            a.y = v.y;
            return a;
        }


        //Загрузить картинку
        bool Load(std::string url,ShaderL &sh,glm::vec3 scale = glm::vec3(1,0.57,1))
        {
            Scalse = scale;
            //Файл с высотой
            FIBITMAP  *dib1 = FreeIMloadImage(url.c_str());
            if (!dib1)
            {
                return false; //ошибка
            }
            Mesh.SH = sh;
            NormalMesh.SH = sh;






            //темп
            int x, y;




            //Удалить массив если бил MeshCreater::VertexOne **masiv;
    
            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
                delete []masiv[i];
            delete []masiv;


            //Для загрузки  текстур
            RGBQUAD rgbquad;
            FREE_IMAGE_TYPE type;
            BITMAPINFOHEADER *header;

            type = FreeImage_GetImageType(dib1);
            height = FreeImage_GetHeight(dib1);
            width = FreeImage_GetWidth(dib1);



            //Инит массив MeshCreater::VertexOne **masiv;
            masiv = new MeshCreater::VertexOne*[width];
            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
                masiv[i] = new MeshCreater::VertexOne[height];




            //С картинки в масив
            header = FreeImage_GetInfoHeader(dib1);
            int scanLineWidh = ((3 * (int)width) % 4 == 0) ? 3 * (int)width : ((3 * (int)width) / 4) * 4 + 4;
            unsigned char * texels = (GLubyte*)calloc(height*scanLineWidh, sizeof(GLubyte));
            for (x = 0; x < width; x++)
                for (y = 0; y < height; y++)
                {

                    FreeImage_GetPixelColor(dib1, x, y, &rgbquad);
                    masiv[x][y].v.y = ((GLubyte*)&rgbquad)[1];
                }
            free(texels);
            FreeImage_Unload(dib1);
            //=====================================

            //Сместить в центр сцены
            Translate.x = -width / 2;
            Translate.z = -height / 2;

//Заполнить вершины текстур координаты и нормали
            for (x = 0; x < width - 1; x++)
                for (y = 0; y < height - 1; y++)
                {
                    glm::vec3 a, b, c, d;//Точки
                    a = glm::vec3(x, masiv[x][y].v.y, y);
                    b = glm::vec3(x + 1, masiv[x + 1][y + 1].v.y, y + 1);
                    c = glm::vec3(x + 1, masiv[x + 1][y].v.y, y);
                    d = glm::vec3(x, masiv[x][y + 1].v.y, y + 1);


                    //Применить трансформации 
                    a = a * scale + Translate;
                    b = b * scale + Translate;
                    c = c * scale + Translate;
                    d = d * scale + Translate;


                    glm::vec2 atx, btx, ctx, dtx;//Текстур корденаты
                    atx = glm::vec2((float)x / (float)width, (float)y / (float)-height);
                    btx = glm::vec2(((float)x + 1.0f) / (float)width, (((float)y + 1.0f) / (float)-height));
                    ctx = glm::vec2(((float)x + 1.0f) / (float)width, (float)y / (float)-height);
                    dtx = glm::vec2(((float)x) / (float)width, ((float)y + 1.0f) / (float)-height);


                    //a
                    masiv[x][y].v = glmToV3(a);
                    masiv[x][y].t = glmToV2(atx);
                    {
                        glm::vec3 s = glm::normalize(glm::cross(c-a, c-b));
                        masiv[x][y].n = glmToV3(s);
                    }
                    
                    //b     *scale + Translate
                    masiv[x+1][y+1].v = glmToV3(b);
                    masiv[x+1][y+1].t = glmToV2(btx);
                    masiv[x+1][y+1].n = masiv[x][y].n;



                    //c
                    masiv[x + 1][y].v = glmToV3(c);
                    masiv[x + 1][y].t = glmToV2(ctx);
                    masiv[x + 1][y].n = masiv[x][y].n;
                    

                    //d
                    masiv[x][y + 1].v = glmToV3(d);
                    masiv[x][y + 1].t = glmToV2(dtx);
                    {
                        glm::vec3 s = glm::normalize(glm::cross(a - b, a - b));
                        masiv[x][y+1].n = glmToV3(s);
                    }


                } //Массив заполнен

            

            NormalMesh.begin();

    //Обнулить меш
            Mesh.begin();
            for (x = 0; x < width - 1; x++)
                for (y = 0; y < height - 1; y++)
                {
                    //c
                    Mesh.Nomal3f(masiv[x + 1][y].n);
                    Mesh.TextCord2f(masiv[x + 1][y].t);
                    Mesh.Vertex3f(masiv[x + 1][y].v);

                    //b
                    Mesh.Nomal3f(masiv[x + 1][y + 1].n);
                    Mesh.TextCord2f(masiv[x + 1][y + 1].t);
                    Mesh.Vertex3f(masiv[x + 1][y + 1].v);

                    //a
                    Mesh.Nomal3f(masiv[x][y].n);
                    Mesh.TextCord2f(masiv[x][y].t);
                    Mesh.Vertex3f(masiv[x][y].v);



                    NormalMesh.Vertex3f(masiv[x][y].v);

                    glm::vec3 p2;
                    p2.x = masiv[x][y].v.x+ masiv[x][y].n.x;
                    p2.y = masiv[x][y].v.y+ masiv[x][y].n.y;
                    p2.z = masiv[x][y].v.z+ masiv[x][y].n.z;
                    NormalMesh.Vertex3f(p2);



                    //a
                    Mesh.Nomal3f(masiv[x][y].n);
                    Mesh.TextCord2f(masiv[x][y].t);
                    Mesh.Vertex3f(masiv[x][y].v);


                    //b
                    Mesh.Nomal3f(masiv[x + 1][y + 1].n);
                    Mesh.TextCord2f(masiv[x + 1][y + 1].t);
                    Mesh.Vertex3f(masiv[x + 1][y + 1].v);

                    //d
                    Mesh.Nomal3f(masiv[x][y + 1].n);
                    Mesh.TextCord2f(masiv[x][y + 1].t);
                    Mesh.Vertex3f(masiv[x][y + 1].v);



                }

            Mesh.end(); //Компилировать графику


            NormalMesh.end();



        }



        void Draw()
        {
            Mesh.draw();
            NormalMesh.draw(GL_LINES);
        }

    };
}
```

Отмечу что источники света вроде работают, но расчет скорее всего работает от позиции точки, а я то думал что за глюки со светом, направление не работает из за некорректных нормалей.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проверил методику расчета и она верна, значит я где то намудрил, буду разбираться. Проверил на едином треугольнике с постоянно подвижными точками. Все ок.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
glm::vec3 A, B, C;
    glm::vec3 NormalA;

    //Анимировать точки
    A = glm::vec3(-5, sin(glfwGetTime())*3, 5);  
    B = glm::vec3(-5, sin(glfwGetTime()/2)*3, -5);
    C = glm::vec3(5, cos(glfwGetTime())*3,5);

    NormalA = glm::normalize(glm::cross(C - A, B - A));

    TesterNormal.begin();
    Tester.begin();

    
    Tester.Nomal3f(NormalA);

    Tester.TextCord2f(0,1); Tester.Vertex3f(A);
    Tester.TextCord2f(0, 0);  Tester.Vertex3f(B);
    Tester.TextCord2f(1, 1); Tester.Vertex3f(C);

    

    

    TesterNormal.Vertex3f(A);
    TesterNormal.Vertex3f(A + NormalA);


    Tester.end();
    TesterNormal.end();

    

    Tester.draw();
    TesterNormal.draw(GL_LINES);
```

В любом случаи расчет нормали normalize(cross(a-b,a-c)) рабочий, Буду копаться в своем коде.

Всем спасибо победа!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `normalize(cross(ab,ac))` ?

Comment: Мне кажется это реализация в шейдере, в функционале с++ не встречал данных функций, тем более не понятно как координаты передать. из реализации. Сейчас погуглю по вашему ответу, вдруг в glm что-то подобное есть.

Comment: нормалайз - деление каждого компонента вектора на длину вектора, кросс - векторное произведение векторов

Comment: Нашёл в библиотеке GLM C++ glm::normalize(glm::cross()) Но что значит запись ab,ac и что делать если у меня координаты точек? Как правильно передать. Что за формат на входе cross у меня же координаты точек а не векторы.

Comment: ab - это вектор, направленный с a в b. По факту, это просто попарная разница координат. Все. Аналогично и с ac.

Comment: Спасибо, Я правильно понял? struct MYv3
{
 float x, y, z;
};

MYv3 a, b, c; //Координаты
MYv3 ab, ac; //Вектора

ab.x = a.x - b.x;
ab.y = a.x - b.y;
ab.z = a.x - b.z;

ac.x = a.x - c.x;
ac.y = a.x - c.y;
ac.z = a.x - c.z;

MYv3 Normal = glm::normalize(glm::cross(ab, ac));

Comment: где то так. но если используется glm, то там есть уже vec3. а значит, то vec3 a,b,c; vec3 ab = b-a; vec3 ac = c-a; (да, там все красиво определено)

Comment: @ЮрійПисанка обратите внимание на то, что для получения правильного вектора, порядок важен

Comment: Благодарю, Да знаю там есть такое написал через структуру, так как не уверен был знакомы ли вы с glm. Маловероятно но вдруг, да и так нагляднее чисто чтобы выразить мысль. Сейчас применю к модели карты висты и отпишу.

Comment: Думаю в glm можно даже так glm::vec3 a,b,c;//Точки
glm::vec3 Normal = glm::normalize(glm::cross(a-b, a-c));

Comment: Не работает расчет. Добавил скрины.

Comment: "Уточнение: нормаль по сути общая для всех трех точек, так как центр нормали всегда в центре координат 0,0,0, а точки находиться в одной плоскости." - Вы уверены, что три точки находиться в одной плоскости? И заодно - где у нормали "центр"?

Comment: Понял я с точки рисовал щас поправлю чтобы с центра треугольника было

Comment: Стоп, а разницы ведь нету. Я рисую нормаль с точки и вторую точку рисую позиция точки + нормаль. И они лежат.

Comment: Скорее всего позже отрисую единственный треугольник и плавающие вершины, опробую, метод не верен, иле ошибка в моем длинном коде где то.

Comment: Нормаль в точке должна быть усреднением нормалей для сходящихся в точке треугольников.

Comment: Если подумать, я всё равно каждой точке считаю свою нормаль, и подразумеваю, что в одной позиции может быть только одна вершина в которой только одна нормаль, что дает мен возможность свет делать мягким (сглаженным).  Я позже метод проверю на едином треугольнике, и исходя из результатов буду двигаться дальше. Это в начале нужно было сделать.

Comment: "Если подумать, ..." - мне Ваши мысли не видны. Я Вам сказал, как должно быть.

Comment: Прости если обидел, метод действительно рабочий.